# Why am I getting this ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>, <class 'NoneType'

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to test my tensorflow model that classifies user drawings but keep getting stuck on this error. I checked the input shapes matched but I don't know what else to do.

Here's my testing code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r'C:\Users\123PC\Desktop\DrawingClassifier\TrainedDrawingModel.h5')
test_image_path = 'face.jpg'
test_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(test_image_path, target_size=(256, 256))
test_image_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image_array = np.expand_dims(test_image_array, axis=0)
test_image_array /= 255.0
print(model.predict(test_image))
```

and here's my model code

```
data=data.map(lambda x,y:(x/255,tf.one_hot(y,250)))
data_length=len(data)
train_size=int(data_length*.7)
valid_size=int(data_length*.2)
test_size=int(data_length*.1)

train=data.take(train_size)
val=data.skip(train_size).take(valid_size)
test=data.skip(train_size+valid_size).take(test_size)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(250, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
logdir='logs'
tensorboard_callback=tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
hist=model.fit(train,epochs=11,validation_data=val,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Full traceback message:

```text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\123PC\Desktop\DrawingClassifier\model\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(model.predict(test_image))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\123PC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\123PC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1105, in select_data_adapter
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Include the full traeback message so we see where this is happening.

Comment: the traceback message says its happening on the model.predict line

Comment: I'll edit the post and put it in because it wont fit in a comment

Comment: The idea was exactly to edit your post, not to post it in the comments space (please keep this in mind for the future). That said, there is neither a `test_image` nor a `model.predict(test_image)` in your posted code

Comment: what are you talking about